# How to word wrap and remove hyphen in react pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I am rendering an email and it shows like this:

[image]

but the actual email has no `-` in it.

when I do:

```
 Font.registerHyphenationCallback((word) => {
    // Return entire word as unique part
    return [word]
  })
```

this just causes the email to go off the edge of the page

What I need is for an email to wrap but the hyphen to be removed

Comment: Seems like it's an active known issue: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1418